# Incremental Word2Vec Model Training in gensim

Tags: python, deep-learning, gensim, word2vec

I have tried to train incrementally  word2vec model produced by gensim. But I found that the vocabulary size doesn't increased , only the word2vec model weights are updated . But i need to  update both vocabulary and model size .

```
#Load data 
sentences = []
....................

#Training 
model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=100)
model.save("modelbygensim.txt")
model.save_word2vec_format("modelbygensim_text.txt")



#Incremental Training 
model = Word2Vec.load('modelbygensim.txt')
model.train(sentences)
model.save("modelbygensim_incremental.txt")
model.save_word2vec_format("modelbygensim_text_incremental.txt")
```

Answer (score 13):

By default, gensim Word2Vec only does vocabulary-discovery once. It will happen when you supply a corpus like your `sentences` to the initial constructor (which does an automatic vocabulary-scan *and* train), or alternatively when you call `build_vocab()`. While you can continue to call `train()`, no new words will be recognized.

There is support (that I would consider experimental) for calling `build_vocab()` with new text examples, and an `update=True` parameter, to expand the vocabulary. While this would let further `train()` calls train both old-and-new words, there are many caveats:

- such sequential training may not lead to models as good, or as self-consistent, as providing all examples interleaved. (For example, the continued training may drift words learned-from-later-batches arbitrarily far from words/word-senses in earlier batches that are not re-presented.)
- such calls to `train()` should use one of the optional parameters to give an accurate estimate of the new batch size (in words or examples) so that learning-rate decay and progress-logging is done properly
- the core algorithm and underlying theories aren't based on such batching, and multiple restarts of the learning-rate from high-to-low, so the interpretation  of results – and relative strength/balance of resulting vectors - isn't as well-grounded

If at all possible, combine all your examples into one corpus, and do one large vocabulary-discovery then training.